# DirectorySearcher sorting behavior

Tags: c#, sorting, active-directory, directoryservices

I want to use DirectorySearcher (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher(v=vs.110).aspx) to find out first 1000 AD objects that has usnChanged field greater than 123456 (sorted by usnChanged in ascending order).

I intent to do the following:

```
DirectorySearcher.Filter= "(usnChanged>=123456)"
DirectorySearcher.Sort = new SortOption("usnChanged", SortDirection.Ascending);
using (SearchResultCollection searchResults = searcher.FindAll())
{
   // enumerate through searchResults assuming there MUST be in order.
}
```

Is this the right way of doing it?

Is "DirectorySearcher.Sort" passed to the domain controller to perform a server-size sort (which guarantees that it will return the 1st 1000 objects with lowest usnChanged field among all AD objects which is way more than 1000)?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks correct to me. Did you get the correct result when you ran it?

Comment: I tried it and use a foreach to loop through all the entries in searchResults. Then I checked the usnChanged field to see if they are monotonically increasing. I let my code run for 12 hours. Majority of times the entries are monotonically increasing. However, there are 2 hits where I got out-of-order (meaning an earlier entry has larger usnChanged field value).

Comment: This prompted me to think hard about the transnational behavior of DirectorySearcher.FindAll(). Since SearchResultCollection is an IEnumerable, what is the behavior if during the enumeration, some AD object got changed (as thus having a higher usnChanged value)? Would it still be enumerated if this higher usnChanged value makes it NOT to be the 1st 1000th smallest?